# Error when trying to create custom Json to XML transformer in Mule

Tags: json, xml, mule, anypoint-studio, transformer-model

I'm trying to create a custom Json to XML conversion in mule (custom transformer), its just a one to one direct mapping values, not a complex transformation.

**here is my flow:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" basePath="/test" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="test_finalFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <json:json-to-xml-transformer metadata:id="57c0cd3d-ece4-48fe-9adf-79fc36a31b12" doc:name="JSON to XML"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

[image]

I'm using theses files to configure my `Json to XML` component

**jsonFile.json:**

```
{
  "inData": "value"
}
```

**xml file: outData.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <outData>someValue</outData>
</root>
```

**setting the metadata:**

[image]

[image]

**right now when I deploy the application I do not have any problem,**

but **when I use postman** to send a POST data with payload **I got these errors:**

[image]

and this is the full output of the console:

```
*******************************************************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* test_final                                    * default                        * DEPLOYED           *
*******************************************************************************************************

ERROR 2017-01-17 21:23:29,014 [[test_final].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : java.io.IOException: Illegal character: <i> (javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException)
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@526ed3db
Transformer           : JsonToXml{this=6993c8df, name='JsonToString', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='text/xml', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.Reader, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.net.URL, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.File, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}]}
Element               : /test_finalFlow/processors/0 @ test_final:test_final.xml:13 (JSON to XML)
Element XML           : <json:json-to-xml-transformer metadata:id="57c0cd3d-ece4-48fe-9adf-79fc36a31b12" doc:name="JSON to XML"></json:json-to-xml-transformer>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Illegal character: <i>
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.stream.impl.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:641)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.stream.impl.Yylex.nextSymbol(Yylex.java:271)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.next(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:107)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.peek(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:250)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:128)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:161)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:216)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.<init>(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:65)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:139)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:120)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:44)
    at org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToXml.doTransform(JsonToXml.java:55)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:366)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.transformMessage(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1589)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1488)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1462)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1454)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.process(AbstractTransformer.java:114)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
```

Any idea about what causing the error ?

> java.io.IOException: Illegal character: i ?

**Note:**

I'm trying to create this custom transformer because I'm using just `Mule server 3.8.1 CE` right now , I'll get access soon to an enterprise edition version that's why I'm trying to deploy in a community edition server at this time.

Answer (score 0):

please refer the below link for creating a custom json to xml transformer

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/creating-custom-transformers